# Thinkpad screen stays blank after resuming from sleep

Tags: 20.04, suspend, thinkpad, resume

Ubuntu 20.04, Lenovo Thinkpad E495 (AMD chipset/graphics)

This laptop frequently won't wake up after sleep, although the LEDs in the lid and various buttons are lit. It's connected to a Lenovo docking station through a USB-C cable, which also has an external monitor attached. When the issue occurs, we are forced to hold down the power button and do a cold boot. Removing the docking cable does not help. Both screens (internal + external) stay blank.

Does anyone have the solution for this?

We have now tried updating the kernel from 5.8 to 5.11, as some posts seem to indicate that the kernel version plays a role in this - can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue on my Lenovo, it may be related..

To fix it I disabled power management functions:
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

If this doesn't work and you need to undo this:
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

Comment: Helpful stuff, James - much appreciated! We'll try this on the next occurrence of the issue.Am I right in assuming that disabling power management functions incurs some kind of "cost"? Loss of some specific functions, perchance?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but I was having this same issue using Debian Bullseye.

Then I noticed when booting that I had an error message saying I was missing amdgpu firmware. Used the following command then rebooted and haven't had any issues since.

```
apt install firmware-linux firmware-linux-nonfree libdrm-amdgpu1 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
```

** Courtesy of https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-drivers-on-debian-10-buster